# how to set value negative value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have issue with my jquery function i am useng one function. i want to set answer with **minus "-"** sign how it is possible using jquery function.

in my **"totalAmt"** class i want to set minus sign with this function result..

```
function finalRate()
{
  var rate      = $('.rate').val() != '' ? $('.rate').val() : 0;
  var diff      = $('.diff').val() != '' ? $('.diff').val() : 0;
  var diffAmt   = $('.diffAmt').val() != '' ? $('.diffAmt').val() : 0;
  var kg        = $('.kg').val() != '' ? $('.kg').val() : 0;
  var gorssRate = 0;
  var totalAmt  = 0;
  var total     = 0;

  if(diff == '-')
  {
    gorssRate = (parseFloat(rate) - parseFloat(diffAmt));
    totalAmt  = (parseFloat(gorssRate) * parseFloat(kg));
    $('.total').val(gorssRate.toFixed(2));
    $('.totalAmt').val(totalAmt.toFixed(2));
  }
  else
  {
    gorssRate = (parseFloat(rate) + parseFloat(diffAmt));
    totalAmt  = (parseFloat(gorssRate) * parseFloat(kg));
    $('.total').val(gorssRate.toFixed(2));
    $('.totalAmt').val(totalAmt.toFixed(2));
  }
}
```

Comment: Multiply the value by `-1`?

Comment: `$('.totalAmt').val('-' + totalAmt.toFixed(2));`

Comment: Thanks working properly.... @j08691